# I want to add items seperate from a ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx

Newbie question. I'm trying to make a javafx to do list class but i need to add a button and textfield to insert data to the listview. I want to add these but I can't add them directly to the listview. I dunno how to do it.

```
package learning;




import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToDoList extends Application{

private ObservableList<String> doList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private String text="";
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    primaryStage.setTitle("2DoList");

    TextField userTextField = new TextField();
    Button enter=new Button("Add");
    enter.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

           text= userTextField.getText();
           doList.add(text);
           userTextField.setText("");
           text="";
        }
    });
    ListView<String> root=new ListView<String>(doList);
    Scene scene=new Scene(root,250,500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Put all three controls (`Button`, `TextField`, and `ListView`) in some kind of [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) and make the layout pane the root of the scene.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to do this but making the layout the root was the key.